# How do I create a categorical legend for imagesc with square legend symbols?

Tags: image, matlab, legend, categorical-data

I have with 5 different values and I would like to create a legend ? 
These are continuous data, I need small coloured squares !
[How to add legend in imagesc plot in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902709/how-to-add-legend-in-imagesc-plot-in-matlab) Something like this but with squares, I tried replacing "line" by "rectangle" but that's not the trick apparently !

Thank you

Comment: please accept answers, if they solved your problem! Not just these, in general, it indicates the system that the problem is solved. Thank you! (There is a green check mark on the left)

Answer (score 2):

I just used your [linked example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902709/how-to-add-legend-in-imagesc-plot-in-matlab) and modified it a little:

```
 N=4;                       %  # of data types, hence legend entries
 Data = randi(N,30,30);     % generate fake data
 imagesc(Data)              % image it
 cmap = jet(N);             % assigen colormap
 colormap(cmap)
 hold on

 markerColor = mat2cell(cmap,ones(1,N),3);
 L = plot(ones(N), 'LineStyle','none','marker','s','visible','off');      
 set(L,{'MarkerFaceColor'},markerColor,{'MarkerEdgeColor'},markerColor);   
 legend('A','B','C','D')
```

The trick is to use markers instead of the line itself.

it returns:

[image]

Comment: Thnx a lot! I have another question. My classes are numbered as integers... but somehow, my class "3" get legend of "D" and not "C", any idea how to solve this ? That would just be awesome ! :)

Comment: @Lay it depends on the order you plot them. Please post your code, otherwise it's hard to help.